# How can I process multi-line records with awk in a bash script?

Tags: scripts, awk

example.txt is below

```
Restaurant: McDonalds 
City: Miami
State: Florida
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911

Restaurant: 5 guys
City: Atlanta
State: Georgia
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 911

Restaurant: KFC
City: NYC
State: NY
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 911
```

Im using bash script and lets say I want to search for a restaurant by its name from the file above. Ask the user input for the restaurant name and it should print the information regarding that restaurant (5 lines).

```
awk '/McDonalds/> /KFC/' example.txt
```

I know that line of code above will print the whole line that matches the pattern "McDonalds" and "KFC" but that will just print the 1st line from the text file but not the rest of the information about that restaurant. How can I tell it to print all of the information (5lines) from just the user input of the restaurant name?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With awk, you can change the *record* separator. By default it is a newline, so each line of the file is a record. If you set the `RS` variable to the empty string, awk will consider records to be separated by blank lines:

```
awk -v name="KFC" -v RS="" '$0 ~ "Restaurant: " name' example.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's quite vague. Is it the assignment or the usage that you don't get?

Answer (score 3):

Using **`sed`**:

```
$ sed -n '/KFC/,/^$/p' file
Restaurant: KFC
City: NYC
State: NY
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 911

$ sed -n '/McDo/,/^$/p' file
Restaurant: McDonalds
City: Miami
State: Florida
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911
```

#### Explanation

This is basic `sed` function, you can refer [USEFUL ONE-LINE SCRIPTS FOR SED](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt)

```
# print section of file between two regular expressions (inclusive)
sed -n '/Iowa/,/Montana/p'             # case sensitive
```

Comment: Add the explanation.

Comment: But why the suggested edit rejected? I did not change the answer. I've just improved formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$2=="KFC" {print; for(i=1; i<=4; i++) { getline; print}}' example.txt

Restaurant: KFC
City: NYC
State: NY
Address: 123 Madison Square
Phone: 911
```

The above command will get and print  the consecutive 4 lines along with the current line because it was fed into a for loop.The search pattern `$2=="KFC"` will helps to get a particular line from  the multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="\n\n"}{if($1=="KFC")print $0}' example.txt
```

Comment: The `{if($1=="KFC")print $0}` can be condensed to just `$1 == "KFC"`, since the default action for a true condition is to print the record.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to print from line containing the name you want, to the last line containing word `Phone` ( assuming of course that all the entries follow the same pattern and will always have `Phone` as terminating record)

```
$> awk '/5 guys/,/Phone/' restaurants.txt                                     
Restaurant: 5 guys
City: Atlanta
State: Georgia
Address: 123 Peachtree Rd
Phone: 911
$> awk '/McDonalds/,/Phone/' restaurants.txt                                  
Restaurant: McDonalds 
City: Miami
State: Florida
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911
```

If we wanted to complicate it a bit, we could print exactly 5 lines after the match, like so:

```
awk '/McDonalds/{stop=NR+5}; NR<=stop ' restaurants.txt                    

Restaurant: McDonalds 
City: Miami
State: Florida
Address: 123 Biscayne Blvd
Phone: 911
```

The `stop` variable will not be set, so `NR<=stop` will not print anything, until `/McDonalds/{stop=NR+5;}` part actually sets the variable, and that will only happen when we find the match.